# Breakpoint on the selenium xpath code line in VS2013

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Using the Visual Studio 2013, c#, i get a prolem while debuging the code on the line

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elColl = UIDriver.driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//li[contains(@class, 'organization') ]//p[@class = 'name']"));
```

When i do stepInto or stepOver to go on, i'am getting this

[image: error]

How to move on debuging instead getting this tab in studio??

Comment: Seem you don't have library `By.cs`. When you break all, you are very likely to break on code that occurs within compiled libraries in your code. The source would not be available for this, hence the error.

Comment: Re-install driver may fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by debugging and stepping into a function call, you have navigated into the source code for the driver which you don't have installed. You should either step over lines like this or you can do some googling to find instructions on how to install the source for the drivers. I'm guessing you don't need to debug the drivers so just stepping over these lines is generally the best solution.